# AngularJS $http GET request to local JSON file returns SyntaxError: Unexpected token ]

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json, http, get

I'm trying to make a simple GET request to a JSON file located within my project directory and keep receiving the following: **SyntaxError: Unexpected token ]**

I don't see any syntactical issues with my JavaScript or JSON. The path to the JSON is correct gives me a 304 response. My JavaScript and JSON are fairly straight-forward:

JavaScript:

```
// app
var app = angular.module('app', []);

// controllers
app.controller('myController', function($scope, $http){

  $scope.data = null;

  $http.get('data.json').success(function(data){

    $scope.data = data;
    console.log($scope.data);
  });
});
```

JSON:

```
{
 "data": [
  {
    "title": "Test 1",
    "description": "Fusce vulputate eleifend sapien."
  },
  {
    "title": "Test 2",
    "description": "Vivamus laoreet."
  },
  {
    "title": "Test 3",
    "description": "Quisque ut nisi."
  },
 ]
}
```

What is preventing me from retrieving the data from within my JSON file?

Comment: it is not a valid json, there is an extra comma after the last element in data array

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Normally, in JavaScript, adding an extra comma to an array/object won't cause any problems (in the code editor, for example), even though it's not best practice.

But since you're using this JSON in a request, the JSON syntax must be correct.

Removed a comma at the end of the array containing objects.

```
{
 "data": [
  {
    "title": "Test 1",
    "description": "Fusce vulputate eleifend sapien."
  },
  {
    "title": "Test 2",
    "description": "Vivamus laoreet."
  },
  {
    "title": "Test 3",
    "description": "Quisque ut nisi."
  }
 ]
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You have an extra comma at the end of your JSON:

```
{
 "data": [
  {
    "title": "Test 1",
    "description": "Fusce vulputate eleifend sapien."
  },
  {
    "title": "Test 2",
    "description": "Vivamus laoreet."
  },
  {
    "title": "Test 3",
    "description": "Quisque ut nisi."
  }, <<<< HERE
 ]
}
```